# awk a variable list

Tags: bash

I'm new on bash programming and actually I didn't find an answer for my topic among the ones just answered.

I got a variable with a list of timestamp values, such as

```
myvar="16:00:01 17:30:00 18:13:12"
```

What I've to do is to fill an array list with each single timestamp. Right now what I'm doing (and it works) is:

```
varlist[0]=$(echo $myvar | awk '{$NF = "" ; print $1}')
varlist[1]=$(echo $myvar | awk '{$NF = "" ; print $2}')
varlist[2]=$(echo $myvar | awk '{$NF = "" ; print $3}')
```

The problem is that putting everything in a for loop like the following, it doesn't give me the single item timestamp but the entire string.

```
for (i=1 ; i<=3; i++)
do
    varlist[$i]=$(echo $myvar | awk '{$NF = "" ; print $i}')
done
```

How can I loop the awk?

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/passing-bash-variable-to-awk.html

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array in bash directly like this:

```
array=($myvar)
```

then:

```
# print # of elements in array
echo ${#array[@]}

# print all the elements in array
echo ${array[@]}

# loop thru your array
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo "i=$i"
done
```

Comment: echo ${#array[@]} gives me 1 as result cause myvar is a string. is there any way to get the number of timestamp inside myvar?

Comment: Also you have a syntax error in `myvar= "16:00:01 17:30:00 18:13:12"` instead of `myvar="16:00:01 17:30:00 18:13:12"`

Comment: my var is a result of a grep command, that's why the lenght I'm getting with this code is 1. Is there any way to get the length?

Comment: As I showed in my demo that any string can be used to create an array. I think it would be better if you post your grep command and how you set myvar also in your question in order to get better targeted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=1 ; i<=3; i++)
do
varlist[$i]=$(echo $myvar | awk -v myi=$i '{$NF = "" ; print $myi}')
done
```

Comment: thnks, it works!!!
what about getting myvar length in order to put it on the for last cycle:
for (i=0; i<$NF;i++)
do
blah blah
done

is it correct?

Comment: what did you mean by length? Is it the number of fields or the number of characters in myvar?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You are tring to use an outside variable (namely: "`$i`") inside Your awk script with single quotes. It (those single quotes) does not allow to interpret the variable.

You can do it this way (if You want to do it with awk, but there are other ways - look up bash array docs).

```
for (i=1 ; i<=3; i++)
do
varlist[$i]=$(echo $myvar | awk -v CNTR=$i '{print $CNTR}')
done
```